# find and copy from filelist with spaces in it

Tags: shell, spaces

I have a list of pdf-files separated by line breaks. (the filenames contain a lot of spaces...)

if I do

```
cat file.list
```

the shell shows some gibberish like

filename.pdfpdf8.pdf

and that's it.

I want to find each rows file and copy it to a dir (Desktop/someFolder).

Comment: So the data inside `file.list` are gibberish. If you are 100% sure the data should be valid, that you are in the correct folder, that it should work for 100% and this is a valid file... well, maybe you can post the output of `hexdump -C file.list` or `cat -A file.list` and inspect for unreadable characters. If you want to [read a file line by line in bash](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+a+file+line+by+line+in+bash) you can find much help online and I recommend [bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) as a good reference.

Comment: `Desktop/someFolder` on Windows? Characters that output gibberish when `cat` to `stdout`. Most likely your file contains *UTF-16* characters that `cat` has no way of dealing with. You can attempt `dos2unix file.list`

Comment: I had some files with "." in the filename. I eliminated them using RegEx. Now my cat call is not gibberish anymore . at least

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pipeline that will do what you need:

```sh
cat file.list | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} Desktop/someFolder
```

1. `cat` will send the list of files to stdin of
2. `tr` which will translate newlines to nulls and send them to
3. `xargs` which expects null-separated arguments (`-0`) and will send each of these to
4. `cp` which will finally copy them to the destination folder.

Comment: I have to find them first, so I need a find between xargs and cp. I don't get how to reference the current line within the find, since it uses {} as the placeholder for the matched file and your copy command uses {} it to reference the argument. I confuses me a little bit

Comment: cat corruptFiles.list | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I{} find . -name '{}' 2>&1 | tee corruptLog.txt    this is what I tried but my log-file is empty. If I  do  -print \; instead of  2>&1 | tee corruptLog.txt. I get "find: +: unknown primary or operator".   I'm using Mac by the way

Comment: @nch68 so some of the files in `file.list` do not exist, and the ones that do only specify the base name and not the full path?

Comment: exactly like so

Answer (score 0):

If your data is valid (see Kamil's comment), a small script like the following can accomplish what you want. Regarding your mentioned "line breaks", I just want to mention that Linux/MacOS/BSD Systems use `\n` and Windows uses `\r\n`. So I'd suggest you do `hexdump -C file.list` as Kamil suggested in the comment and then you should see if it's necessary to do some substitutions before using the script or adjusting the field separator (newline, space, tab are default).

**Note:** The `find .` command searches in the current directory (`.`), so you may want/need to change that, unless all the files listed in `file.list` are in/below the current directory.

```
#! /bin/bash

dir="$HOME/Desktop/someFolder"
if [ ! -e "$dir" ]; then
  mkdir "$dir"
fi
while read -r ; do
  name=$(find . -name "$REPLY")
  cp -v "$name" "$dir"
done < file.list
```